# How to use Observables instead of document.querySelector in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, getelementbyid

I need to use  Observables instead of  document.querySelector in Angular 6. My code looks now like this:

```
onInputChange(result: string) {

const x = document.querySelector('.x') as HTMLElement;

if (result[0] === '4') {
  x.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';


} else if (result[0] === '5' && result[1] === '5') {
  x.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';


} else if (result[0] === '_') {
  x.style.backgroundColor = '#AFB8BD';

}

result = result.replace(new RegExp('u', 'g'), 'x');
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('someInput')).value = result;
}
```

Actually, the main idea is to change color of the  background regarding the first number of "result" input 
Could someone help me to use Observables? I'm new in Frontend so sorry for this question

Comment: It seems like you're looking for this https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I think your issue **does not** revolves around observables. You wish to change some color of element as a response to some other element action (let's assume on click, because this is not provided in your snippet)

Just use some standard `onClick` event listener to set other component style:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">
<div [class]="classFromController"
```

and in controller:

```
onClick() {
  if (/* any logic you wish */) {
    this.classFromController = 'black';
  } else if (/* other logic */) {
    this.classFromController = 'white';
  }
}
```

In your css

```
.black {
  backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
}
.white {
  backgroundColor = '#000000';
}
```

Avoid inline styles, because they are considered as terrible coding style and are easy to avoid.

If for some special reason you must use observables, consider using `Observable.fromEvent()` as referred below:

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent

Comment: @JulieR good to know, but as I already mention, at least from code you provided, observables really seems not needed in your case. Anyway, glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

The problem to your question is, that we don't really know what your components are

Angular provides you two ways to interact with component and events

- [How to reference elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template) & [fromEvent (rxjs)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html)
  You get an element reference to interact and listen with your component/snippet. Then you listen for an event with the *fromEvent* operator from rxjs

```js
const yourEvent = fromEvent(button, 'click');
```

- [Component interaktion with Input and Ouputs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) Read this documentation. Angular provides you the posibility to interact with datastreams and events from and into components by [input] and (ouptut) events.

Example:

```html
    <input type="text" #comp (keyup)="onChange(comp.value)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the main idea is to change color of the  <div> background regarding the first number of "result" input

Comment: @JulieR I think you mean to have an observable on the event of change in 'result' input... take a look at https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html

Comment: If your component doesn't provide an Angular event you can use fromEvent() true :) Well done sir. I will add it to the answer if it's ok for you?